Proving that a function from one metric space to another is continuous or discontinuous at a point
I want to know if my work with this is sound, since the teacher only gave us the definition of continuity but no examples on how to prove or disprove it. We are given two metrics, $d_1 = \text{discrete metric}$; and $d_2$ defined as $d_2(x, y) = |x - y|$ so just the standard real line metric. We are also given a function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$:
\begin{align*}
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
   x^2+1 & x > 1 \\
   x & x \leq 1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
And we are asked, if this function continuous at the point $x = 1$ in each of the following cases:

$f \colon (\mathbb{R}, d_2) \to (\mathbb{R}, d_2)$
$f \colon (\mathbb{R}, d_1) \to (\mathbb{R}, d_2)$
$f \colon (\mathbb{R}, d_2) \to (\mathbb{R}, d_1)$
$f \colon (\mathbb{R}, d_1) \to (\mathbb{R}, d_1)$

For cases 2 and 4 I am pretty sure that any function that goes from any set with the discrete metric, will always be continuous everywhere, since you can pick any $\delta < 1$ and it wil work no matter the value of $\epsilon$, so I'll skip those.
For case 1, it's clearly not continuous at $x = 1$, the function is continuous iff $(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})(d_2(x, 1) < \delta \implies d_2(f(x), f(1)) < \epsilon)$. So it will not be continuous if the negation of this is true, that is, if: $(\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall \delta > 0)(\exists x \in \mathbb{R})(d_2(x, 1) < \delta \land d_2(f(x), f(1)) \geq \epsilon)$. I claim that this $\epsilon$ exists, in fact I claim that $\epsilon = 0.1$ works as our counterexample.
To show this, first notice that no matter how small, for every $\delta > 0$ there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $1 < x < 1 + \delta (*)$ and this implies $|x - 1| < \delta$ which implies $d_2(x, 1) < \delta$. Another consequence of $(*)$ is that $x^2 > 1$ which implies $|x^2| > 1$ and this implies $|x^2 + 1 - 1| > 1$ and this is equivalent to $|f(x) - f(1)| > 1$, which is the same as $d_2(f(x), f(1)) > 1 > \epsilon$. So we have shown there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that no matter what $\delta > 0$ we pick, there will always be an $x \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $d_2(x, 1) < \delta \land d_2(f(x), f(1)) \geq \epsilon$. As a consequence, the function is not continuous at that point.
For case 3, it is also discontinuous, first notice that $f$ is injective. No matter what value of $\delta$ is picked, there will always be $x \neq 1$ such that $d_2(x, 1) < \delta$, then it follows that $f(x) \neq f(1)$ which means $d_1(f(x), f(1)) = 1$. So really any positive $\epsilon < 1$ will do as a counterexample.

When proving the discontinuity of a function, you can use the sequential characterization of continuity. Here's an application for question n°1 :
Let $x_n=\frac{n+1}{n}>1$ defined for any integer $n \geqslant 1$. This sequence clearly converges to $1$. Then you have $ f(x_n)= \left( \frac{n+1}{n} \right)^2+1$ which converges to $2 \neq 1=f(1)$. This proves that $f$ is not continuous for $x=1$.
Other than that, you did a good job. I don't see mistakes.

Thanks! I always thought the sequential criteria was useless since it's harder to prove a statement about all sequences rather than just proving about a function. But I guess it's better to disprove continuity or the limit, since you only need to find one counter example sequence.

@zlaaemi It a very powerful tool indeed. There's also a version for uniform continuity which is even more valuable in my opinion

Looks fine! Indeed every function with discrete domain is continuous, and your epsilon-delta proof of the other cases are good.
